# Which Projection system to use for area calculation in Bangladesh (in South Asia)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, geometry, bangladesh

I am vectorizing a raster layer using ArcScan. I need to calculate the area of the vectorized feature after the vectorization process.

What projection should I use for the vectorized polygon layer to calculate the area of the polygon?

Geographic location for the layer is: Bangladesh (in South Asia)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use "Gulshan 303 / Bangladesh Transverse Mercator" ([EPSG:3106](https://epsg.io/3106)) or one between [EPSG:32645](https://epsg.io/32645) and [EPSG:32646](https://epsg.io/32646), respectively "WGS 84 / UTM zone 45N" and "WGS 84 / UTM zone 46N", if the zone of interest falls only into one UTM zone. You can use the same projection code in ESRI.